# How to create this design in Bootstrap with flex boxes or columns? (Sketch inside)

Tags: bootstrap-5

I try to realize this following design in bootstrap v5 and REACT by using flex boxes and/or conventional grid for a user interface.

https://ibb.co/N6cyX4n

The green container is embedded in the rest of the design of the REACT app and spans over the complete available viewport height. In the background of this container is an image (grey contour, looking like a swimming pool). This works fine.

Now I want to orientate the blue an red containers as shown. The big blue box can be also in the background. The red boxes and the small blue boxes below have to be in the foreground.

First I tried to orientate the red containers to start with the simplest task. ;-)

```
export default function FunctionnameinUI(props) {
    const styles = {
        bgimage: {
            backgroundImage: `url("urltoimage")`,
            backgroundPosition: "center",
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundSize: "100%",
        }
    };
    return(
        <div className="container border" style={styles.bgimage}>
            <div className="row border justify-content-around">
                <div className="col-4">
                        <ComponentNameinRedBox />
                </div>
                <div className="col-4">
                        <ComponentNameinRedBox />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Unfortunately I ended just with try and error. Any recommendations how to find a solution for this kind of design?
Thanks!